# Initializing linked list with elements in a treeSet

Tags: java, linked-list, set

The question is this:
Define a constructor that takes a TreeSet as a parameter and initializes a linked list with the elements in the set. The new list must be sorted in increasing lexicographic order.

This method is to be implemented using the class below:

```
public class LinkedList<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    private class Node{
        private T data;
        private Node next;

        private Node(T data){
            this.data = data;
            next = null;
        }

    }

    private Node head;

    public LinkedList(){
        head = null;
    }
```

Now I know a TreeSet is inherently sorted so all I'd really have to do here is take the element from the TreeSet and put it to the front of this linked list. But I'm having trouble retrieving the element from the set and adding it to the LinkedList. I wrote a private helper add(T data) method and am using it but I don't know if this is how I should approach it. I'm new to data structures so have little idea about sets and their implementations.

```
public class LinkedList<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    private class Node{
        private T data;
        private Node next;

        private Node(T data){
            this.data = data;
            next = null;
        }

    }

    private Node head;

    public LinkedList(){
        head = null;
    }

    public void add(T data){
        Node n = new Node(data);
        if(head == null){
            head = n;
        }
        else{
            n.next = head;
            head = n;
        }
    }

    public LinkedList(TreeSet<T> test){
        Iterator<T> itr = test.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()){
            this.add(itr.next());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well does it work? You're supposed to have a question, not just dump a pile of code and say "so, whatcha think?".

Comment: I did kind of mention that it works. I just wanted to see if there was a better approach to doing this or if this was "convention." I just winged it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem you have to solve is that you need to add each item to the end of the list not the start.

Adding a node to the start of the list is easy:

```
public void addToHead(T data) {
    Node node = new Node(data);
    node.next = head;
    head = node;
}
```

Adding to the end is harder because you don't have a reference to the tail. But the solution is fairly simple: in the constructor you are developing, keep a reference to the tail of the list so that you can add each value at the end of the links rather than the start.

Answer (score 1):

The question includes "increasing lexicographic order."

My solution is without helper method:

```
    public LinkedList(TreeSet<T> test){
        Node currNode = null;
        for(T data : test) {
            Node newNode = new Node(data);
            if(head == null) {
               head = newNode;
               currNode = head;
            }
            else {
               currNode.next = newNode;
               currNode = currNode.next;
            }

        }
    }
```